# How to password protect a stream on Wowza?

Tags: wowza

After setting up a stream, if possible, can you password protect the stream whenever you may access the stream, like I enter the IP address on VLC and then the stream require a password.

Comment: Check out these articles, depending on whether you're using Wowza Streaming Engine media server software or the Wowza Streaming Cloud service. https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-security-using-wowza-streaming-engine-manager https://www.wowza.com/docs/security-features-in-wowza-streaming-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Wowza SecureToken](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-protect-streaming-using-securetoken-in-wowza-streaming-engine). It allows you to generate a unique token for each video stream that is something like "StreamName|Password". So even if somebody gets the token for one video stream, unless they know the hashing algorithm, they can't use it to access other streams.

Good luck.